# Why does the perforated tin foil on a shisha pipe rise when smoking?

Tags: pressure, air

Imagine this setup (just without the windguard):
[image: shisha pipe wikimedia diagram]

When applying negative pressure at the hose, I can observe the perforated tin foil separating the charcoal from the bowl rise a few millimeters, which seems odd, because the pressure above it should be greater than below.

Why does this happen? Maybe because of vortices forming below it?